# how to automate creation of view or synonyms to another database and which to use

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a database maintained by a program. During updates all stored procedures are wiped out. I create reports using stored procedures so all of my custom stored procedures have to be scripted then reloaded when upgrades are done. Also, during the process of using tools within the software views will be created that link two tables. one being an original table and the other typically being a custom fields table.

I have a new database where I want to create the stored procedures that would remain unchanged during upgrades. That being said I have the following questions. What is the best way to do this.

View to the tables which are in one schema and views to the view which are in another but create it in a way that all the views I create are in one schema giving precedent to the views rather than tables. Create synonyms to the tables and views.

The next question would be how to script this to create the object because there are hundreds of tables and view.

Script 1 would create the synonym or view and script 2 can find all the tables or views. how would I be able to run them together or would I just have to use script 2 to create scripts to run in the second database.

Any suggestions would be great and any help understanding which would be best views or synonyms would be great. I want to learn not just be given the answer and if there is any other ideas to accomplish my goal of separating the stored procedures from the main db would be great.

```
***Script 1***
    create synonym table1 for db1.dbo.table1

***Script 2***

select a.name from sys.tables a
        inner join sys.schemas b
            on a.schema_id = b.schema_id
    where a.type = 'U'
```

Comment: SQL tag on this website is meant for valid ANSI/ISO SQL code only. this SQL dialect   [CREATE SYNONYM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) seams  to be SQL Server (MSSQL) related?

Comment: Thank you. My apologies

Answer (score 1):

You could generate script:

```
select 
  FORMATMESSAGE('CREATE SYNONYM %s FOR db1.%s.%s;',  -- here goes template
                 QUOTENAME(a.name),
                 QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(b.[schema_id])),
                 QUOTENAME(a.name)
                ) AS query_to_run
from sys.tables a
inner join sys.schemas b
     on a.schema_id = b.schema_id
where a.type = 'U';
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=abea79b80c4f75bb50cd7a2c56a5a7e3)**

Using metadata you could build any kind of script, then copy the result from SSMS grid to query pane and execute it.